# QGIS 3.4 Spatial Join error message interpretation

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, error, spatial-join

I had a problem when spatial joining two polygon layers.
The error message says:
" Feature (182) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option. "

How I'm supposed to discover wich feature has the (182) associated to it? Is this information obtained by ID column? What if I don't have a ID column? Or is that number associated to the current order of the attribute table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options.

The mas recommendable is that you use the `tools of topology` to locate the entity with problems.
[image]

Then you can activate it by clicking on the
[image]

Then click on the settings button, then configure the first rule, to do this select your layer, in the different options you will find the

> "must not have invalid geometry"

, select it and add the rule with the green cross. Clic Ok

[image]

Before continuing I recommend you to assign to your layer a single symbol with a color that contrasts with the red, it can be yellow, blue, green.

Finally click on the check button as seen in the image, you highlight in red the invalid entities and you number them in the dialog box, including the ID.
[image]

**Other options:**

The ID is the sequential number as the entities are created you can add it to the table of attributes

Open the attribute table, activate the field calculator, add a new field, search for the expression `"record and attributes"` and enter $id